# How do I import or include jquery and its plugins inside Vue component?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, plugins, datatables, integration

Jquery can be imported via "import" inside a component(in export default object) and is used in life-cycle hook called "mounted". But when I import plugins like

```
import DataTables from "@/assets/scripts/directory1/jquery.dataTables.js"
```

it doen't work. Is there a method to include jquery plugins in Vue application and use them inside mounted hook? Where and how should I include them to be able to use them?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method to include jQuery and it's plugins is to include `script` Tags in your HTML. As jQuery is then globally available, you can use it everywhere - even in your Vue components.

Comment: Why you should try to combine Vue AND jQ is beyond me. Don't do that, if you can somehow avoid such a scenario!

Comment: I've tried to include script tags in html file but I've got errors:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'".

Comment: Please provide more context on what you've tried so far and what is not working. [ask]